# One to Many and Many to One xml mapping in hibernate With Join tables

Tags: java, hibernate

I am not asking about the differences b/w these 2. After reading the hibernate documentation, i decided to implement them so as to clarify my concepts.

One to Many

1 person linked to Many Addresses

a Set holding the objects of class Address is declared in Person.

```
CREATE TABLE person_address
(
  person_id integer NOT NULL,
  address_id integer NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT person_address_pkey PRIMARY KEY (person_id, address_id),
  CONSTRAINT fk9e2338ea36645cd5 FOREIGN KEY (person_id)
      REFERENCES person (person_id) ,
  CONSTRAINT fk9e2338eaa1a53d5f FOREIGN KEY (address_id)
      REFERENCES address (address_id) ,
  CONSTRAINT person_address_address_id_key UNIQUE (address_id)
)
```

In the above case, 4 constraints gets created by Hibernate.

Now have a look at the other mapping.

Many to One

Many Persons linked to a Single Address

a reference of Address class in Person class.

```
CREATE TABLE person_address
(
  person_id integer NOT NULL,
  address_id integer NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT person_address_pkey PRIMARY KEY (person_id),
  CONSTRAINT fk9e2338ea246188ab FOREIGN KEY (address_id)
      REFERENCES address (address_id) ,
  CONSTRAINT fk9e2338eaf88b7809 FOREIGN KEY (person_id)
      REFERENCES person (person_id) 
)
```

As you can see there are 3 constraints which Hibernate creates. 
It makes complete sense that PRIMARY KEY is (person_id), since different persons are linked to 1 address.

I know the clear-cut differences b/w Primary key and unique keyword.

My question is why Hibernate created the Primary key in the first case to be combination of (person_id, address_id), even knowing that the address_id is unique and could be used as a Primary Key just as in the Second case(Many to One).

Edited :

```
        <key column="PERSON_ID" />
        <many-to-many column="ADDRESS_ID" unique="true"
               class="org.academy.ansar.UnidirectionalOneToManyMappingWithJoinTable.Address" />
```

Specifying unique = "true" changes it from many-to-many  TO  one-to-many

Answer (score 0):

> ... My question is why Hibernate created the Primary key in the first case to be combination of `(person_id, address_id)`, even knowing that the `address_id` is unique and could be used as a Primary Key just as in the Second case *(Many to One)*.

In the first case, table **`person_address`** is a pairing table between to tables, `person` and `address`. And to make the **answer** really obvious, let's have these records:

Person table

```
1 - PersonA
2 - PersonB
```

Address table

```
1 - AddressX
2 - AddressY
```

And now, we can have these combinations in the pairing table `person_address`:

```
   personId, addressId
   1       , 1
   1       , 2
   2       , 1
   2       , 2
// 2       , 2  - impossible due to primary key
```

And that is the **answer**:

- `addressId` is **not** unique
- `personId` is **not** uniq
- combination of them **is unique**

That's how `many-to-many` does work...

Comment: I am in no way asking you Many to Many. The first case is clearly mentioned to be One to Many, for which Hibernate creates 4 constraints, pasting it here also : CONSTRAINT person_address_pkey PRIMARY KEY (person_id, address_id),
  CONSTRAINT fk9e2338ea36645cd5 FOREIGN KEY (person_id)
      REFERENCES person (person_id) ,
  CONSTRAINT fk9e2338eaa1a53d5f FOREIGN KEY (address_id)
      REFERENCES address (address_id) ,
  CONSTRAINT person_address_address_id_key UNIQUE (address_id).  ofcourse address_id is unique as per hibernate.

Comment: The first table, created by Hibernate has all identifiers, that it is many-to-many. In fact as the second, but I thought you made a mistake. If I am wrong, ok, but could you then extend your answer and show the mapping which caused that?